# Is it a bad idea to make redundant rows when 2 columns reference to the same table?

Tags: database-design, rdbms

Suppose we have this database design

```
Users table:
- id
- name

Friends table:
- id
- user_id
- friend_user_id
```

Let's say `USER 1` befriended `USER 2`, this is what my application logic will execute:

```
INSERT INTO friends (user_id, friend_user_id) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO friends (user_id, friend_user_id) VALUES (2, 1);
```

For the retrieval of the `USER 1` friends, we simply query this:

```
SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user_id = 1
```

**Is it a bad idea to make redundant rows when friending users?**

What I am trying to avoid here is not to store the friendship in a single row and keep guessing in every query which column the user is in:

```
SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user_id = 1 OR friend_user_id = 1
```

The latter made my application logic very complicated in some cases.

Comment: "friend" type relationships are a great use case for a graph database, rather than a purely relational model.  Have you considered using graph for your relationship model?

Comment: That would be ideal. Unfortunately, our app is based on a relational database and we can't just switch like that. Appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: You might want to tag your existing database engine, if that's a limitation. Some RDMBSs have graph support, so you may still be able to use graph, depending on what DB engine you're tied to.

Comment: Side note: `friends` table probably doesn't need an `id` column

Comment: I assume in this case that "friendship" for the purposes of this example is always mutual?

Comment: @bbaird yes it is mutual!